# PHP code in counting duplicate letters in two words

Tags: php, on-duplicate-key

hi there i'm a newbie in php and i would like to ask how to write a code that will out put the number of duplicated letters in two words.
    for example: "apple" and "ball" in overall it has a 7 same letters (a,a,p,p,l,l,l) thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Sven I think OP means duplicate letters among both words.

Comment: And "b" is not in the output. As long as we do not know the correct output, a solution is a little more complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$a = 'apple';
$b = 'ball';

$duplicates = array_count_values(array_merge(str_split($a), str_split($b)));

// Array ( [a] => 2 [p] => 2 [l] => 3 [e] => 1 [b] => 1 )
print_r($duplicates);
```

If you want to get the total number of matches among the words, you could then do this.

```
$totalMatches = 0;

foreach($duplicates as $count) {
    if($count > 1)
        $totalMatches += $count;
}

// 7 matches!
echo $totalMatches . ' matches!';
```

Comment: thankyou so much sir austin but for now how about counting the remaining non duplicate letters? example: "christine" and "tin" it will only output 6, because of (chrise) thanks again

Comment: You can just do `count($duplicates) - $totalMatches`.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient but arguably simple:

```
$word1 = "apple";
$word2 = "ball";
print_r(array_count_values(str_split($word1.$word2)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [p] => 2
    [l] => 3
    [e] => 1
    [b] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this:

```
$a= "apple";
$a.=  "ball";
print_r(array_count_values(str_split($a)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [p] => 2
    [l] => 3
    [e] => 1
    [b] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str1   = "apple";
$ar1    = str_split($str1);

$str2   = "ball";
$ar2    = str_split($str2);

$res    = array_merge($ar1,$ar2);
$count  = array_count_values($res);

print_r($count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to make array from string and then compare array itself and other for duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str1 = 'applle';
$str2 = 'ball';
$str1arr = str_split($str1);
$str2arr = str_split($str2);
$all = array_merge($str1arr, $str2arr);
$countall = count($all) - count(array_intersect($str1arr, $str2arr));
echo "count of similar charactors (overall) =".($countall);//7!

?>
```